# How to calculate SDNN (HRV) from RR intervals in Matlab or Mysql

Tags: mysql, matlab, data-analysis

I have RR-interval data in next format (.txt)

```
Time (ms),HR (bpm),R-R (ms)
642,93,655
1296,96,654
```

And I want to calculate SDNN, for example for 60 sec. in Matlab, mysql or somehow (I want to get HRV from RR-intervals).
[Formula for SDNN (60 sec.) is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbc0G.png)

And it is very important to save time data. So, I will be glad to get such table:

```
Time (ms), SDNN
2314     , 50
......
```

Any help would be appreciated...
And sorry if it is a not right question. Thank you

Comment: In my case N=60, (RR) underlined on top = is the mean value of RR intervals

Comment: the question is not clear at all. Are you asking about how to collect the data, how to store it, or how to implement the calculations formulae provided in the picture? you [need to elaborate](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), if you want to get an answer.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for reply. I have RR-intervals and I want to calculate SDNN (or SDANN) from these RR-intervals. So, the question is How to calculate this SDNN from RR-intervals in Matlab for example. And Time should be save, it is important for me.